# Loop through JSON array in PLSQL 12.1

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have JSON array inside varchar

```
DECLARE
 JsonArray varchar2(1000);
 arrayCars varchar2(1000);      
BEGIN
  JsonArray :={"Cars": [{"name":"Honda", "color":"red" },
                        {"name":"Toyota", "color":"green"}] }
  SELECT JSON_QUERY(JsonArray, '$.Cars') into arrayCars FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Now if I print out arrayCars i will get

> [{"name":"Honda","color":"red"},{"name":"Toyota","color":"green"}]

But how can I loop through this Cars array and print out it's components seperately (get access to them)?

Comment: PL/SQL is not needed to extract the desired portion, using SQL is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly use `SQL` with [`JSON_TABLE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973) function which is available starting with `Oracle DB 12.1.0.2` version such as

```
WITH t(arrayCars) AS
(
 SELECT JSON_QUERY('{"Cars": [{"name":"Honda", "color":"red" }, 
                              {"name":"Toyota", "color":"green"}] }', '$.Cars') 
   FROM dual
)
SELECT name, color
  FROM t
 CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(arrayCars,
                       '$' COLUMNS(NESTED PATH '$[*]'
                                    COLUMNS(
                                            name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.name',
                                            color VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.color'
                                            )
                                  )
          );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2d25bfc15916d078937c6b16490e5cf0)</kbd>

If you really need to use `PL/SQL`, then consider creating a function with `SYS_REFCURSOR` return type such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Cars RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  JsonArray   VARCHAR2(1000);
  arrayCars   VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);  
BEGIN
  JsonArray :='{"Cars": [{"name":"Honda", "color":"red" },
                         {"name":"Toyota", "color":"green"}] }';
  arrayCars := JSON_QUERY(JsonArray, '$.Cars');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(arrayCars);

  v_sql := 
  'SELECT name,color
     FROM dual
    CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(:Cars,
                          ''$'' COLUMNS(NESTED PATH ''$[*]''
                                      COLUMNS(
                                              name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH ''$.name'',
                                              color VARCHAR2(100) PATH ''$.color''
                                              )
                                    )

            )';
  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql USING arrayCars;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

and then call from SQL Developer's console as

```
SQL> DECLARE
    result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :result := Get_Cars;
END;
/

SQL> PRINT result ;
```

**Edit(***for your last comment***):**

Alternatively, you can use a simple implicit loop such as

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  v_name   VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_color  VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
   FOR c IN (
             SELECT name,color
               FROM JSON_TABLE('{"Cars": [{"name":"Honda", "color":"red" },
                                          {"name":"Toyota", "color":"green"}] }',
                                    '$' COLUMNS(NESTED PATH '$.Cars[*]'
                                                COLUMNS(
                                                        name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.name',
                                                        color VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.color'
                                                        )
                                                )
                               )
            )
   LOOP
     v_name  := c.name;
     v_color := c.color; 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name||'  '||v_color);
   END LOOP;                            
END; 
/
```

<kbd>[Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=231b545c1532256d5d15ba4fe716e8fa)</kbd>

Comment: Can you run your code with JSON declared into variable like in my example ?
When I try this I get ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
This is critical for me. The whole JSON must be inside varchar variable

Comment: I've added the case for PL/SQL @David

Comment: I think this is a bit complicated for me, Is there any way to do a bit more easy?
Without sql functions, straight inside plsql for example here you get the array
 arrayCars := JSON_QUERY(JsonArray, '$.Cars');
Then I need just loop through that array and use those variables for something. Lets say we have some testVar varchar and just add all variables to it inside loop.
testVarchar:=testVarchar+Honda;
then testVarchar:=testVarchar+red;
then testVarchar:=testVarchar+Toyota;
then testVarchar:=testVarchar+green;

Comment: I mean I need some loop action where I can do something and use hondas variables, then do something and use toyota variables.